# OxyPlot: How can I add text to a graph?

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, oxyplot

I am using OxyPlot.Xamarin.Android to plot irregular polygons (LineSeries), I want also to add near a line it's length. It is possible to add a text in a graph? I also want the zoom in or out to work on the text like on the lines.
Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> It is possible to add a text in a graph?

You could try to use `TextAnnotation`.
For example:

```
        var plotModel = new PlotModel { Title = "OxyPlot Demo" };

        ///Other code...
        ///...
        ///...
        ///...

        var textAnnotation = new TextAnnotation
        {
            Text = "Text1",
            TextPosition = new DataPoint(1.0, 2.0)
        };
        plotModel.Annotations.Add(textAnnotation);
```

Comment: Thanks, even if the zoom in/out is not working on textAnnotation, it will do just fine.